# Потеря указателя в конструкторе

Tags: c++, c++11

Добрый день!
У меня есть базовая диалог-система и столкнулся с проблемой потери указателя переданного в конструктор.

У меня есть дочерний класс,который вызывает конструктор базового,передавая параметр дальше :

```
SceneTwo(shared_ptr<ContentManager>* manager) : GUIElement::GUIElement(manager) { }
```

В базовом классе в конструкторе мы инитим необходимый protected параметр, для будущего доступа к нему из дочерних классов.

```
GUIElement::GUIElement(shared_ptr<ContentManager>* manager)
{
    _contentManagerPtr = manager;
    _sceneContainer = _contentManagerPtr->get()->sceneContainer();
}
```

И вот,что интересно - когда дебажишь, на момент входа в

```
GUIElement::GUIElement(shared_ptr<ContentManager>* manager)
```

manager - содержит в себе указатель, но сделав 1 итерацию дальше меня кидает на 3 шага в GUIElement.h , там инитятся переменные и вернувшись уже в тело конструктора - manager параметр не корректен ... http://prntscr.com/c082oc

Comment: думаю, Вам нужно собрать "минимальный пример, который воспроизводит проблему"

Comment: Вы зачем-то передаете умный указатель по указателю. Тем самым счетчик при присваивании не увеличивается. Возможно, далее просто происходит удаление объекта, которым управляет `shared_ptr`

Comment: Извините,что с такой задержкой появился тут)
Вероятно,Павел,вы правы.
У меня просто есть менеджер базовый,который хранит линки на сторонние модули. И их я по запросу отдаю по ссылке, специально,чтоб каунтер не повышался и при деструкте базового менеджера все приложение красиво закрывалось(вобщем премудрости).
Но я отдаю ссылку по такому формату


`return &static_pointer_cast<ManagerType>`


И получается при static_pointer_cast создается копия и она уничтожается?